# How to get all alt attributes of all img tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My html code:

```
<img src="" alt="google.com">
<img src="" alt="gmsil.com">
<img src="" alt="gmail1.com">
```

How to get all the alt values of `img` tag?

Answer (score 5):

try this : You can make use of `attr()` method of jquery object. Iterate all images and call `$(this).attr('alt');` to get the alt attribute value.

```js
$(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('alt'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src = "" alt="google.com">
<img src = "" alt="gmsil.com">
<img src = "" alt="gmail1.com">
```

Comment: `attr()` isn't strictly needed here. `alert(this.alt);` will do just fine.

Comment: yeah, it is one of the way to read `alt` thats why I said You can make use of `attr()`

Answer (score 4):

You can get all alt's as an array using `map()` like following

```js
var alts = $('img').map(function () {
    return this.alt;
}).get();
alert(alts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src = "" alt="google.com">
<img src = "" alt="gmsil.com">
<img src = "" alt="gmail1.com">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('alt'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgAltTagArr=[];
$('img').each(function(){
    imgAltTagArr.push($(this).attr('alt'));
});
alert(imgAltTagArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){

console.log($(this).attr('alt'));

})

working fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gub4qs2e/